# react-admin calls getList twice on sorting

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a Datagrid inside a List with custom sorting and filtering. Everything works fine except that when the function that updates the sorting is called, the getList method is called twice (the server is called twice, which is very time consuming).

Here is the fucntion responsible of updating sorting field and order:

```
const handleSort = (key) => {
    console.log("key for sorting        :", key);

    const {field, order} = sort;

    console.log("field and order: ", field +"  "+order);

    if(field === key) {
        sort.order = order === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";
    } else {
        sort.field = key;
    }

    setSort(sort);

    refresh();
}
```

What could probably be the cause of this ?

**Edit:**

Actually I found that every simple click anywhere on the web page causes react-admin to call getList with the current url (to refresh the page). Is there a way to disable this behaviour or to control it ?

Comment: Do you have any effects/logic when the component renders, that would cause a request when the state changes?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to answer this question.

Comment: Actually even the built-in sort gives the same behaviour: two calls to get List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first request was actually done on windows focus as dictated by React pareameter **refetchOnWindowFocus**, which has the value true by default.

I changed its value to false in the queryClient prop of the Admin object like the following:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: 10000,
      retry: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});

return <Admin
    queryClient={queryClient} />
...
  </Admin >
```